# get current page url and change action

Tags: zend-framework, url, action

I need to give current page url and change action url. After that I want echo that in view file.
I want do these in view file, not controller!

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get current page url as follows:

```
  $uri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();

  // or using userAgent view helper:
  $uri = $this->userAgent()->getServerValue('request_uri');
```

The view helper `$this->userAgent()` returns an instance of `Zend_Http_UserAgent` that can provide you with many useful info.

If you want to get an action in your views you can get it as follows:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Not sure what you mean by 'changing an action'. You want to change it when you echo it, or you want to redirect user. Anyway, hope this will help.

Comment: @afsane. You could get current action and url as I wrote, and use `str_replace` to change url's part with action to something else.

Answer (score 5):

If your current scope is a controller action, you can do this:

```
$uri = $this->view->serverUrl() . $this->view->url();
```

Answer (score 2):

> $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
>   $fullUrl = 'http://' .
>   $front->getRequest()->getHttpHost() .
>   $front->getRequest()->getRequestUri();

Don't forget protocol(in this example `http://`) if you are going to use `$fullUrl` for `href` attributes

Comment: For the scheme, you can do `$front->getRequest()->getScheme()`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party for sure, but the following worked for me in a Zend 1 project:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->serverUrl(true)); ?>
```

If you're echoing out the (user supplied) URL on the page, it's a good idea to use htmlspecialchars() to avoid someone sending your users to `http://example.com/?q=<script>nastyBusiness()</script>`.